# pyQt4 - How to select table rows and disable editing cells

Tags: python, pyqt4

I create a QTableWidget with:

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
self.table.setObjectName('table')
self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
```

with this selection it is possible to select rows but I don't want that the user can edit any cells of this table. I know that you can enable each cell while filling the table. But is there a possibility to set the cells of the whole table kind of inactive (after the filling of the table) while the selection of the rows is still possible?

TIA Martin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use

```
self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

([here you can find other triggers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum), just in case you need them)

Comment: Now there is another problem. When I select rows and move the curser between columns, the value of the last cell the mouse is over (with pressed mouse button) gets the value of the first cell. I am using:   self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

Comment: Uhmmm..it seems something related to Drag & Drop....disable it if you don't need it..

Comment: I tried it with self.table.DragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoDragDrop) but this has no effect.

Comment: How would this been looking as code? (Sorry I am new in pyqt)

Comment: self.table.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)  ;)

Comment: Does not work, too. It seems like when I set the selection behaviour with self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows) this occurs. When I don't write a selection behaviour it works normally...

Comment: I tried with these settings


`self.table.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.table.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoDragDrop)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)`

and for me is working: i drag cells over row and columns but nothing changes..

Comment: Thank you! Yours is working. Now I found the place where the error with the drag-and-drop occurs. I color the selected rows like this:
    
 `brush_gray = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(232,232,232)
    brush_gray.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    
    for d in del_list[]: #contains the selected rows
        for i in range(col): #col contains the number of columns
            self.table.item(r,i)setBackground(brush_gray)`

If i comment this part the selection works perferctly. But as soons as this is in it doesn't work.

Comment: is there a way to disable editing specific rows/cells, and leave the rest editable?

Comment: @raf I need something like that. I would like edit the current (activ) row and lock the all other rows. I do it with `setFlags` but it clear all my row data- **please moderator attention!**

Comment: Note that in PyQt5 the correct line of code will look something like this: 
`self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)`

Answer (score 4):

You can disable editing by setting the flags `ItemIsSelectable` and `ItemIsEnabled` for each item in your table:

```
table = QTableWidget(10,10)

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(i*j))
        item.setFlags( Qt.ItemIsSelectable |  Qt.ItemIsEnabled )
        table.setItem(i, j, item)
```

Comment: This helped to skip some cells i don't want be in my taborder in my qtablewidget.Thanks!

Comment: @SahilJain glad it helped ;)

Comment: In PyQt5, the imports are `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` and `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget`.